# hiding/show elements with same class name individually

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem I have is selecting (hide/show) list items based on the content of their children

I can't add or change the ids or classes (these are set by the crm and will vary)

I need to hide/show information depending on what is selected. eg. "hide the list items that contain the words 'Accommodation Type' in the child div that is of class type 'Title'"

So it would hide this list item:    please only list item with accomodation type in the child div should be hidden.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>New Web Project</title>
            <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("li").
                var title = $("li").find('div[class=Title]').html();        
                if(title == "Accommodation Type")
                {
                    $('div[class=Title]').parent().parent().hide();
                }

            });
            </script>

        </head>
        <body>
            <ul>
    <li>
    <div class="Group">
    <div class="Title">Accommodation Type</div>
    <div class="Item">
    <select>
    <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
    <option value="30393382">Motel</option>
    <option value="30393383">Hotel</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="Group">
    <div class="Title">Adults</div>
    <div class="Item">
    <select>
    <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
    <option value="30393382">1 Adult</option>
    <option value="30393383">2 Adults</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    </li>

    </ul>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [`:has`](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_has.asp) selector with the [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector

```
$("li:has(div.Title:contains('Accommodation Type'))").hide();
```

Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/8k5tnpjm/

Comment: Nice inline solution, even though selector is quite hard to read.

Comment: @Regent I find it pretty simple to read. Select  li that has div.title containing 'Accommodation Type'. It is pretty linear. Personal opinion obliviously!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an iterator and test the inner content of each `li` like so:

```
$('li').each(function(index, elm) {
  var title = $(this).find('div[class=Title]').html();
  if (title == 'Accommodation Type') {
    $(elm).hide();
  } else {
    $(elm).show();
  }
});
```